# Independent random variables, sigma

Tags: probability, measure-theory, independence, expected-value

Let $(X_n) $ are independent integerable random variables about the same distribution. Let $S_n=X_1 +.....+X_n$ and $G_n=\sigma(S_n,S_{n+1},.....)$. Calculate : $E(X_1|G_n)$. I tried but i don't have any idea

Comment: Knowing $S_n$ and $S_{n+1}$ only really tells you $S_n$ and $X_{n+1}$, so knowing all the higher $S_n$ tells you nothing. There's a place to start.

Comment: Could you explain me more clearly?

Comment: Essentially $E(X_1 \mid G_n)=E(X_1 \mid \sigma(S_n))$ because knowing the higher sums doesn't give you any new information (since, once you have $S_n$, all it is telling you about is the $X_m$ for $m>n$ which don't help you to determine $X_1$). As for $E(X_1 \mid \sigma(S_n))$, keep in mind that they didn't tell you what the distribution actually is, so somehow this must necessarily be some simple, generic function of $S_n$.

Comment: Okey I undestand this now thank you very much. But is it possible to write this formal? Can i use now that $E(X_1|\sigma(S_n)=E(X_1|S_n)$?

Comment: Someone have more tips?